# Why is it an issue if media queries "snap" from one set of rules to the next?

Tags: css, media-queries

The following quote comes from here: http://www.creativebloq.com/css3/create-fluid-layouts-html5-and-css3-3142768

"Any fixed-width design, using only media queries to adapt for different viewports, will merely 'snap' from one set of CSS media query rules to the next with no linear progression between the two."

But, I can't help but wonder why this matters. Sure, the transitioning is smooth and looks pretty when a developer is playing around with browser size, but what visiting customer (on an ecommerce site or blog) is realistically going to be doing this?? In general, visitors will visit on one device at a time, click around, then leave. Even if they come back on another device, smooth transitioning isn't necessary for the UX, so, why do we care about linear progression between media queries?

Comment: I don't know. I'd like to hope that the article is really referring to the fact that at, say, 960px a fixed layout may still use the min-width: 600px size because it's still technically not min-width: 1000px, resulting in a waste of horizontal space. This is the main disadvantage fixed layouts have compared to fluid layouts and has been known since the dawn of web design. But the way it's written it does seem like it implies people go around resizing their browser windows and such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This became a practical issue for us in one of our eCommerce clients, the "change" in size would occur when someone switches from landscape to portrait (especially in devices like iPhone where the width is significantly different) i.e. hoding the device vertically and then shifting to horizontal or the other way around and in fact since we used media queries there was a very minor delay (a fraction of a second) in the layout adopting to the new width.

Another realistic scenario is that people may switch between restored and maximised versions of browsers , then again as commented, wasting spaces is also an issue.

Comment: Restoring down isn't nearly the same thing as manual resizing though.

Comment: @BoltClock I agree, primarily our practical experience is the device switching

Comment: @skv I think you nailed it regarding maximizing browsers. The author says, "we need to switch our fixed, pixel-based layouts to fluid, proportional ones. This will enable elements to scale relative to the viewport until one media query or another modifies the styling."

I then checked his sample site http://www.andthewinnerisnt.com/index.html 

Even if you don't resize the browser, the site is completely fluid at all zoom levels. Whereas a site like this http://www.stylinonline.com/ isn't. I find that I do happen to zoom in & out (when visiting sites) more so than resizing browsers.